# Is there a (language-agnostic) name for the string operators such as $=, ^= found in e.g. CSS?

Tags: string, language-agnostic, operators, string-comparison, relational-operators

There is a set of operators, used e.g. in CSS attribute selectors or in youtube-dl's format selection syntax, that are similar to the more conventional relational operators such as == but select the beginning, the end, etc.
Specifically, I am thinking of the operators `*=, ^=, $=` and less commonly `~=, |=`
The syntax itself (e.g. `$` for at the beginning of the string) presumably originates with regex (or perhaps something even earlier), but in the same way as we can group `==, <=, >, etc.` into the 'relational operators', is there a name for the mentioned string operators?

Comment: In the context of how you ask, [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) as used with Regular Expressions might be what you seek.  I say in the `context of how you ask` because I don't think of data as strings but as list of items and processing of the list using recursion with Prolog, so tend to think of accessing items when recursing over the list and depending upon what I seek I may access the data when recursing forward or backtracking.